# Percentage pie chart in Tableau with one value

Tags: tableau-api, pie-chart

I have multiple measures and different dimensions. Lets say one dimension is a university and one measure is a number (integer or float) which shows a score for that university. The score is always out of 100. (Let`s say 75 in here.) Now I am going to add a kind of percentage pie chart in tableau like the following to have a graphical presentation for the score.

[image]

The yellow area is 75 (which is the score for the university out of 100.) So there is only ONE value and ONE dimension. But I am little bit confused about how to do it. I am not sure if I should create a calculate field or even the specific keyword here that I should be looking for. Any thought would be appreciated!

**Edit**: I am using tableau **version 10.3**

Answer (score 3):

Create a calculated field `[to100]` with the following formula:

```
100 - [Score]
```

and set up your workbook like this(Replace `[Answer]` with `[Score]` in your example):

[image]

Drag `SUM(Answer)` to label and set it up like this to get the single label:

[image]

You might want to play around a bit with positioning and format to place it in the circle.